# Compare cell to range of cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two columns of cells with numbers. For each cell in column B, I want to check whether column A has a value less than it. If column A has a lesser value, return True otherwise return False. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to compare each cell in column B against all values in column A, you can use:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,"<"&B1)>0,TRUE,FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the minimum value in column A and compare it with the value in a particular cell of B, say B1.

```
=IF(B1 > MIN(A1:A5), TRUE, FALSE)
```